# Camel - Passing specific parameters from routes to processor

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to setup a route that process files, here is my route configuration:

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    public static final String FIRST_ROUTE = "firstRoute";
    public static final String SECOND_ROUTE = "secondRoute";

    private final Processor myProcessor;

    @Autowired
    public MyRoute (@Qualifier("my.processor") Processor myProcessor) {
        this.myProcessor= myProcessor;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("file://{{data.input.dir}}?moveFailed=errors&delete=true&doneFileName=ACK-${file:name}&include=MY-FILE-FIRST.*")
                .routeId(FIRST_ROUTE)
                .process(myProcessor);

        from("file://{{data.input.dir}}?moveFailed=errors&delete=true&doneFileName=ACK-${file:name}&include=MY-FILE-SECOND.*")
                .routeId(SECOND_ROUTE)
                .process(myProcessor);

    }
}
```

As you can see I have two route for two files that have different name (one with FIRST, one with SECOND).
I want to trigger the process with variable to avoid to check the filename inside the process.

Currently my process function look like that:

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
```

What I want is something like that:

```
public void process(Exchange exchange, String identifier) throws Exception
```

And have the identifier set in the route definition (it's static, not depending on the filename, I need to have `"FIRST"` for the first route, and `"SECOND"` for the second one).

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Because a process interface signature only takes an Exchange parameter, we cannot do `process(Exchange exchange, String identifier)`.
Instead we can create a bean and call the method from the route like below.

```
 from("file://{{data.input.dir}}?moveFailed=errors&delete=true&doneFileName=ACK-${file:name}&include=MY-FILE-SECOND.*")
                .routeId(SECOND_ROUTE)
                .bean(myBean,"process(*, " + SECOND + ")");
```

Comment: You also have the option of setting an exchange property and referencing it in the processor as well.